# Flink consumer job is unable to connect to Kafka from Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple streaming Flink Scala job which connects to a Kafka topic and maps its

*org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord* messages and map into Json string.

When it is running in IntelliJ it ingests the topic well and printing out the jsons.

When I run it in docker-compose I got the following exception:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error constructing instance of class: org.apache.avro.Schema$LockableArrayList
Serialization trace:
types (org.apache.avro.Schema$UnionSchema)
schema (org.apache.avro.Schema$Field)
fieldMap (org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema)
schema (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record)
    at com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$$anon$1.newInstance(KryoBase.scala:136)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1061)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.create(CollectionSerializer.java:89)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:93)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:22)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:143)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:21)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:657)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.copy(KryoSerializer.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.TupleSerializer.copy(TupleSerializer.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.TupleSerializer.copy(TupleSerializer.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:635)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:612)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:592)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:727)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.emitRecord(KafkaFetcher.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:150)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:715)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$ can not access a member of class org.apache.avro.Schema$LockableArrayList with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:413)
    at com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$.$anonfun$normalJava$1(KryoBase.scala:170)
    at com.twitter.chill.Instantiators$$anon$1.newInstance(KryoBase.scala:133)
    ... 37 more
```

I tried forcing Avro serialization with:

```
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.getConfig.disableForceKryo()
env.getConfig.enableForceAvro()
```

but got the same error.

Based on [this][1] I'm using all Flink related dependencies as "provided" with no good result.

- What can be the difference between running the job in the IDE and in
  Docker?
- How can I fix the job to be able to read the Kafka topic from
  Docker?
- How shall I setup Docker for this?
- What can I handle Kryo/Avro serialization issue?

SS
[1]: http://www.alternatestack.com/development/com-esotericsoftware-kryo-kryoexception-unusual-solution-upgrading-flink/

Comment: This seems to be a dependency issue. When you run the job in the IDE, it uses "provided" dependencies defined in your pom.xml/build.gradle. However, in Docker it expects the same libraries to already reside in `flink/lib` folder.

So, my guess is that the "provided" dependencies version in `flink/lib` do not match the ones in your pom/gradle file.

Comment: I use SBT as a build tool. Earlier I assembled everything into a fat JAR file (used no provided dependency) but had the same exception.

using this merge strategy:


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski n Docker I use flink:1.9.3 as a base image. It should contain the necessary provided dependencies, should not it?
how can I check the dependencies which are provided by the IDE itself?

Comment: as far as I understand, it picks up the dependency from SBT. Is it 1.9.3 there as well ?

Comment: @MikalaiLushchytski yes it is 1.9.3 everywhere in the project

Comment: and if I run the fat Jar file without a flink cluster, just simply *java -jar*, it also runs smoothly

Comment: Migth this answer be helpful then ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59874421/14058374

Comment: could solve it using [this idea](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/AvroInputFormat-Serialisation-Issue-td20146.html) .

needed to add **classloader.resolve-order: parent-first** to _flinlk-conf.yaml_